# (tidyverse approach) calculating rowsum across several columns where info on columns to include comes from a different data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assume the following data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  x2 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                  x3 = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                  x4 = c(7, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  x5 = c(7, 2, 1, 4, 5))
```

Further assume the following lookup table:

```
lookup_positions <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,3,5),
                               v2 = c(1,2,5),
                               v3 = c(1,3,4),
                               v4 = c(2,3,5))
```

Now, what I want to do is the following: for each row in `dat` I want to go through all combinations specified in `lookup_positions` and calculate the row sums for the `dat` column ***positions*** specified in `lookup_positions`.

So for all rows in `dat` I want to calculate the row sum of `dat[,c(1,3,5)]`, then I want to calculuate the row sum of `dat[, c(1,2,5)]` and so on. So I basically calculate 4 row sums.

I know how to do it in base R using a loop, I also now how to do it in tidyverse approach for ***one*** row sum, but not how to do it for all versions mentioned in `lookup_positions` with tidyverse without loops.

So expected outcome would be:

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsum1 rowsum2 rowsum3 rowsum4
1  1  2  3  7  7      11      10      11      12
2  2  3  4  2  2       8       7       8       9
3  3  4  5  3  1       9       8      11      10
4  4  5  6  4  4      14      13      14      15
5  5  6  7  5  5      17      16      17      18
```

Here's what I got for one of the lookup_positions in the tidyverse. But I'm stuck in how to generalize this for all lookup positions.

```
dat %>%
  mutate(rowsum1 = apply(across(everything()), 1, function(x) sum(x[as.numeric(lookup_positions[1,])])))
```

I know for my 4 lookup positions I could simply do a copy paste and be done with it, but my real life data has a few hundred lookup position combinations.

Comment: check ```?rowSums()``` from ```tidyverse``` package.

Comment: There is no rowSums function in tidyverse.

Comment: Also, the problem is not how to calculate the row sum, my problem is generalizing my approach to do it across my several lookup_positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map2(.x = asplit(lookup_positions, 2),
     .y = 1:ncol(lookup_positions),
     ~ dat %>%
      mutate(!!paste0("rowsums", .y) := rowSums(select(., .x)))) %>%
 reduce(full_join)

  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsums1 rowsums2 rowsums3 rowsums4
1  1  2  3  7  7       11       10       11       12
2  2  3  4  2  2        8        7        8        9
3  3  4  5  3  1        9        8       11       10
4  4  5  6  4  4       14       13       14       15
5  5  6  7  5  5       17       16       17       18
```

Comment: Interesting. I can't say that I fully understand waht's going on here, but I'll definitely try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution you may be interested in

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(
    lookup_positions %>% rename_with(~str_replace(., "v", "rowsum")), 
    ~rowSums(.y[, .x]), 
    across(everything())
  ))
```

Output

```
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsum1 rowsum2 rowsum3 rowsum4
1  1  2  3  7  7      11      10      11      12
2  2  3  4  2  2       8       7       8       9
3  3  4  5  3  1       9       8      11      10
4  4  5  6  4  4      14      13      14      15
5  5  6  7  5  5      17      16      17      18
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a package [{dplyover}](https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover/) on github which can help with this kind of tasks. In this case we can use `over` to loop over the `lookup_positions`, use each column as input to an `across` call that we then pipe into `rowSums`. We can create nice names on the fly adding `rowsum` in the `.names` argument and then deleting the `v` with a `gsub` in the `.names_fn` argument.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover/

lookup_positions <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,3,5),
                               v2 = c(1,2,5),
                               v3 = c(1,3,4),
                               v4 = c(2,3,5))

dat %>% 
  mutate(over(lookup_positions,
              ~ across(all_of(.x)) %>% rowSums,
              .names = "rowsum{x}",
              .names_fn = ~ gsub("v(\\d$)", "\\1", .x)))

#>   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsum1 rowsum2 rowsum3 rowsum4
#> 1  1  2  3  7  7      11      10      11      12
#> 2  2  3  4  2  2       8       7       8       9
#> 3  3  4  5  3  1       9       8      11      10
#> 4  4  5  6  4  4      14      13      14      15
#> 5  5  6  7  5  5      17      16      17      18
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Alternatively, if we can give the `lookup_positions` `data.frame` nice column names and then use it in a similar approach within `purrr::mapdfc`.

```r
library(purrr)

lookup_positions <- tibble(`rowsum1` = c(1,3,5),
                           `rowsum2` = c(1,2,5),
                           `rowsum3` = c(1,3,4),
                           `rowsum4` = c(2,3,5))

dat %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(lookup_positions,
                 ~ across(all_of(.x)) %>% rowSums))

#>   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsum1 rowsum2 rowsum3 rowsum4
#> 1  1  2  3  7  7      11      10      11      12
#> 2  2  3  4  2  2       8       7       8       9
#> 3  3  4  5  3  1       9       8      11      10
#> 4  4  5  6  4  4      14      13      14      15
#> 5  5  6  7  5  5      17      16      17      18
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For the records (I know not tidyverse :-) using `data.table` and base R.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)

rowsumX <- gsub("v", "rowsum", names(lookup_positions))
dat[, by=seq_len(nrow(dat)), 
  (rowsumX) := lapply(lookup_positions, function(x) sum(unlist(.SD)[x]))
]
```

Output

```
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 rowsum1 rowsum2 rowsum3 rowsum4
1:  1  2  3  7  7      11      10      11      12
2:  2  3  4  2  2       8       7       8       9
3:  3  4  5  3  1       9       8      11      10
4:  4  5  6  4  4      14      13      14      15
5:  5  6  7  5  5      17      16      17      18
```